# Converting a string into html elements to run javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am trying to read the response from an xhr request. I do not want to try to use regex to parse the information. Is there anyway to convert the response string into html elements so I can use document.getElementsById() to read the information I want? The solution cannot use jquery.

Edit: The format is regular html from an xhr response. I am trying to get the information out of divs ie.

```
<div class="name">John Doe</div>
```

Comment: It isn't very clear what your response is, but it sounds like you want to fill some element's innerHTML with it

Comment: the response is in regular html. I am trying to get information out of divs like this

<div class="name">John Doe</div>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure no problem, if your response is HTML, just create a DIV and shovel your response into it. Not sure about your mention of getElementsByName though, that's not a standard DOM function as far as I know.

```
var xhrResponse = "<span id='status'>SUCCESS</span>";

var clipboard = document.createElement("DIV");
clipboard.innerHTML = xhrResponse;
var searchingForSomething = clipboard.getElementById('status');
console.log(searchingForSomething.innerHTML); // => SUCCESS
```

Your temporary DIV never even has to be in the document for this to work.

Comment: Getting elements by class, however, without jQuery, is verbose. You can do it by searching the whole tree, the simplest code being recursive, or if you only support high-end browsers you can use querySelector.